# How to get around "Application failed codesign verification"

Tags: ios, app-store

I am a contractor, building an app that will be published by another company.  I have been using a Development profile to test with my device, and an Ad-hoc Distribution profile to share the app with a group of testers via TestFlight.  This all works fine.

I am having trouble submitting the app to Apple.  I tried creating an IPA signed with their App Store profile, but they were unable to submit it with Application Loader (this is their usual work flow).  They shared their iTunes Connect admin login with me so I could try submitting it from Xcode.

Both approaches give the same error: `Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.`

What are my options here?  I have tried deleting and remaking the App Store profile.

Comment: Is your application profile Distribution App Store profile. Your profile should not be distribution Adhoc profile

Comment: Have you built it with your developer certificate? or theres? That may be your problem, you may need to import their developer certificate if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of Apple.  I just had to revoke my certificate, issue a new certificate signing request, and recreate all my provisioning profiles.  I changed my Apple ID's email address recently, so it was probably related to that.

More details on starting fresh here https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6